# Vb.net cell validating firing on last instance of cell not current instance Radgrid Telerik

Tags: vb.net

I have looked high and low for a solution and I can't find anything about anyone who has the same issue- in short when i validate a cell it doesn't validate what I have written in the cell but what the cell was when I entered it. Ie/ If "CO" is already in a cell and then i edit it with "DO"- it validates with the previous instance CO. Everything i have read suggest cell validation should be for the current writing within the cell. I am using VB- Winforms- VS2015. Here is my code. It is driving me crazy as all of the tutorials I have read suggest this code should work.

```
Private Sub radGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As CellValidatingEventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.CellValidating

    Dim currentRow = RadGridView1.CurrentRow
    Dim Row As Integer = RadGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim temp As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To FormGeoDicLith.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
'if current row is selected and in edit mode then check the value written in the cell against all values in a column of a different datagrid

        If RadGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(8).IsCurrent AndAlso Me.RadGridView1.IsInEditMode Then

'if true then call it temp 1 

            If RadGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(8).Value = FormGeoDicLith.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Then
                temp = 1
            End If
        End If

    Next
'if untrue then prevent movement out of cell until correct value is entered

    If RadGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(8).IsCurrent AndAlso Me.RadGridView1.IsInEditMode Then
        If temp = 0 Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MsgBox("Code not in Dictionary")

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note also using .net 4.0

Comment: My Grid is not bound to anything- Anyone have any ideas why it doesn't register what is entered in the cell until after the validation event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer after much stress and wanting to pull my hair out (if i had any) is the Active Editor Value. Updated Code

Private Sub radGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As CellValidatingEventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.CellValidating

```
    Dim currentRow = RadGridView1.CurrentRow
    Dim Row As Integer = RadGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim temp As Integer = 0



    For i As Integer = 0 To FormGeoDicLith.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1



        If RadGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(8).IsCurrent AndAlso Me.RadGridView1.IsInEditMode Then




            If RadGridView1.ActiveEditor.Value = FormGeoDicLith.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Then
                temp = 1

            End If
        End If

    Next
    If RadGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(8).IsCurrent AndAlso Me.RadGridView1.IsInEditMode Then
        If temp = 0 Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MsgBox("Code not in Dictionary")

        End If
    End If






End Sub
```